# supabase + react native: Access token not refreshed after a week of inactivity

Tags: react-native, expo, supabase, refresh-token, supabase-js

I use the @supabase/supabase-js (v2.23.0) sdk in my expo react native application.

To initialise the react native client I do

```
createClient(
  '<supabaseUrl>',
  '<anonKey>',
  {
    auth: {
        storage: AsyncStorage as any,
        autoRefreshToken: true,
        persistSession: true,
        detectSessionInUrl: false,
    }
  }
```

The expiration of the jwt access token is set to 3600s (1 hour) in the supabase dashboard.

While users are using the app, I can see in the logs that tokens keep being refreshed and indeed the user can continue to use the app without any issues as long as the user frequently uses it. So the `autoRefreshToken` seems to work fine.

The issue arises when a user does not use the app for more than a week. Then the token refresh does not seem to work anymore.

I have a generic method as a wrapper around making calls with the supabase client like this

```
  const selectMethod = modifier
    ? modifier(supabase.from(key).select(select))
    : supabase.from(key).select(select);
  const { data, error } = await selectMethod;
  if (error) {
    if (error.message === 'JWT expired') {
      supabase.auth.signOut();
    }
    throw error;
  }
```

That way the user will be redirected to the login page. I could verify, that after the week of inactivity I will start receiving 'JWT expired' responses. I added this, because otherwise the user would just not be able to query any data without knowing what is going on.

My first assumption was that the refresh token expires after one week, but according to [this discussion](https://github.com/orgs/supabase/discussions/3482#discussioncomment-1456844) refresh tokens don't expire.

I found [another discussion](https://github.com/orgs/supabase/discussions/889) where several people reported issues specifically with react native. So I am wondering if there is an issue with using the AsyncStorage with the supabase client.

Does anyone have an idea why refreshing the token would stop working after a week of inactivity?

Comment: What version of supabase-js are you using?

Comment: I was using v2.23.0 I think at the time of the post, updated post accordingly!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using `expo-secure-store` as outlined in the docs: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/tutorials/with-expo#initialize-a-react-native-app

```js
import 'react-native-url-polyfill/auto'
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store'
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'

const ExpoSecureStoreAdapter = {
  getItem: (key: string) => {
    return SecureStore.getItemAsync(key)
  },
  setItem: (key: string, value: string) => {
    SecureStore.setItemAsync(key, value)
  },
  removeItem: (key: string) => {
    SecureStore.deleteItemAsync(key)
  },
}

const supabaseUrl = YOUR_REACT_NATIVE_SUPABASE_URL
const supabaseAnonKey = YOUR_REACT_NATIVE_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY

export const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseAnonKey, {
  auth: {
    storage: ExpoSecureStoreAdapter as any,
    autoRefreshToken: true,
    persistSession: true,
    detectSessionInUrl: false,
  },
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I should really exchange it. However the SecureStore is still an asynchronous operation and after some long debugging and observation I have the assumption there is a race condition, firing requests before the correct accessToken is initialised and that is giving the JWT expired response in rare cases. I swapped the line supabase.auth.signOut(); with supabase.auth.refreshSession(); and will also see if that helps solving the issue

Comment: hi how did you solved? have you used context to catch expired token?